# Drupal 7 img src path issue

Tags: media, search, uri

I created a block, in which an img with src="sites/mysite/files/imagename". It works every node, but failed loading in search page.

Is this an issue of Search module?
Drupal 7, I hope, has a uniform url management, for example:

- exapmle.com/files, exapmle.com/modules/Module_name, or
- exapmle.com/modules/core(Symbolic Link points to sites/all/modules) /Module_name
- exapmle.com/themes/Theme_name, or
- exapmle.com/themes/core(Symbolic Link points to sites/all/themes) /Theme_name ...
- ...

Answer (score 4):

For any source or path of any thing in drupal site use src like this. It will work everywhere.`$src = base_path() .'sites/files/logo.png';`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a site where there were a lot of nodes with user-written links with relative paths. Something that I found noteworthy: It turns out that using *clean urls* can mess up references to relative paths, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24819214/drupal-7-clean-url-and-relative-path-its-doesnt-work). When you have clean urls enabled, you shoud better use absolute paths in your links.